# Are stock exchanges publicly traded companies themselves?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

Are the new york stock exchange, or nasdaq, or any other stock exchanges actually also publicly traded companies themselves? Can one buy shares of a stock exchange operation? If so, what are some stock symbols for stock exchanges?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [NYSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Stock_Exchange) used to be public but it merged with [Intercontinental Exchange (ICE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_Exchange).

The [NASDAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasdaq) trades under [NDAQ](https://www.google.com/search?q=ndaq&gws_rd=ssl).

For others, google: "Publicly Traded Exchanges"

Comment: ICE is public so the exchange is as publicly traded  as Nasdaq really: Stock price: ICE (NYSE) US$91.74

Comment: Providing the same symbol that I provided adds what information?

Comment: The wording of your answer is misleading: "used to be public" implies that this is no longer the case.  MD-Tech's comment points out that post-merger it is still public, which is not clear from your answer.  You might want to rephrase so that it refers to only the NYSE old ticker in the past tense, and public trading in the present tense.

Answer (score 9):

Down here in Australia, the Australian Securities Exchange trades on itself under the symbol [ASX](https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/ASX).

Comment: Has anyone ever tried to argue that this is a conflict of interest?

Comment: Not that I've heard, but I can see how you could arrive at that conclusion. They do have to answer to the Australian Securities and Investment Commission, though. I haven't heard anything about ASX getting into trouble with them, but certainly have about the banks. At least one of them tends to run afoul of ASIC every couple of years, and we had some big insurance company getting into trouble a year or two ago as well (can't remember who, sorry).

Answer (score 5):

Polish stock exchange trades on GPW under ticker GPW :)

Answer (score 1):

In the US there are three main exchange companies who carry most of the volume traded:

- Intercontinental Exchange (ICE) who own NYSE, NYSE Arca, Amex are listed NYSE under ticker symbol `ICE`.
- NASDAQ Inc.  who are listed on NASDAQ under ticker symbol `NDAQ`.
- CBOE Global Markets who are listed on their equities exchanges under ticker symbol `CBOE`.

The listing of an exchange on its own platform is very common, as for an exchange not to be listed would be a little bit hypocritical - how can you persuade other companies to list when you are not listed yourself?  Typically *information barriers* are put in place to ensure that conflicts of interest do not happen.  Ultimately a *market maker* takes much of the responsibility of ensuring there is a market for the exchange's stock rather than the exchange.